# Combine two tables and show the unique data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in mysql, `tender_items` and `item_price_add_manual`.

Both the tables have fields called `itemName` and `tender_id`. So my requirement is how will i write a query to join these tables and show only certain `itemNames` with eg:

`tender_id` = 460. So the result in php comes like

```
 tender_id | ItemName
 ______________________
 460         Item 1
 460         Item 2
 460         Item 3
```

Is this possible with just a query or i need to manipulate with php script?

I TRIED THIS

```
    SELECT tender_items.item_name,
   tender_items.tender_id,
  item_price_add_manual.item_name,
  item_price_add_manual.tender_id
  FROM tender_items INNER JOIN item_price_add_manual ON     tender_items.tender_id=item_price_add_manual.tender_id WHERE tender_items.tender_id=460
```

With the above query iam getting the result as follows:

```
 tender_id | ItemName  | tender_id   |   ItemName
 __________________________________________________
 460         Item 1      460           Item 3
 460         Item 2      460           Item 3
```

But i am expecting the result as follows:

```
 tender_id | ItemName
 ______________________
 460         Item 1
 460         Item 2
 460         Item 3
```

Comment: Iam sorry, i did the same. Relatively new to stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like all you need is a `UNION` operation:

```
(SELECT item_name, tender_id
FROM tender_items 
WHERE tender_id=460)

UNION 

(SELECT item_name, tender_id
FROM item_price_add_manual 
WHERE tender_id=460)
```

As stated in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from
>   the result.

Hence your requirement for distinct values selection will be satisfied as well.

Comment: Yes iam nearing to the solution now. When i tried the above query, actually tender_items have 2 records. But when i ran the query its showing only one record? am i making any mistake?

Comment: @SanjuMenon The query returns a unified result set combining values from *both tables*. There is no way to tell which records came from which table. You can add a separate field for this purpose.

Comment: @SanjuMenon Also, there is *no way* that the query with `UNION` returns *less* rows compared to `SELECT item_name, tender_id FROM tender_items WHERE tender_id=460`.

Comment: @Giorgos, when i ran the select statement (SELECT item_name, tender_id FROM tender_items WHERE tender_id=460) its showing 2 records. But these two records have same name. May be its excluding the duplicates?

Comment: @SanjuMenon I think I have clearly stated in my answer that any duplicates are filtered out by my query. I thought this is your intention (you mention *unique data* in the subject of your question). If want duplicates returned as well, then simply replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine. Thank you for your time. Union All solved my issues..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT item_name,tender_id FROM

((SELECT item_name, tender_id
FROM tender_items 
WHERE tender_id=460)

UNION 

(SELECT item_name, tender_id
FROM item_price_add_manual 
WHERE tender_id=460)) AS T
GROUP BY item_name,tender_id
```

Comment: You are right. I missed it.`item_price_add_manual_units` --> `item_price_add_manual.units`, i guess

Comment: i have edited the question with the query which you mentioned..pls check it.

Comment: @Drew. Pls see the latest edit. I have mentioned the exact problem. Iam sorry for this.

Comment: @Drew bro  -> shoul br sis .. iguess

Comment: i HAVE EDITED THE ANSWER

Comment: Yes its sis only bros...:) Yes i tried the edited query but getting an error  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT.. I FORGOT TO GIVE ALLIASE TRY NOW

Comment: Its working fine now, only one issue which iam facing is, actually tender_items have 2 records and both the records itemNames are same. But when i ran the query its showing only one record? am i making any mistake? Is it its excluding duplicates. Any way to include the dupicates as well?

Comment: I did not get ,please explain in detail.

tender_items have 2 records and both the records itemNames are same `but tensed_id` will be different right?

Comment: Union All solves that issue. Actually some itemName are same. So i guess it was taking the distinct values.

Comment: try to not use CAPS. and read up on on Giorgos' union all. just saying. +1 for effort. Thanks for helping *her*

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have a foreign key which have linked the 2 tables together. You need not link everything from one table to another as it makes things very complex and erroneous may occur, making things hard to debug. You may look at [W3School school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp/) to know how to `SELECT` specifically.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tender_items, item_price_add_manual WHERE tender_items.tender_id = item_price_add_manual.tender_id AND tender_id = 460";
```